# Htaccess RewriteRule add HTTP/1.1 at url end

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need this url:
    www.99bankinfo.in/index.php?bank=AxisBank

to
    www.99bankinfo.in/AxisBank

but it appears this:
    www.99bankinfo.in/AxisBank%20HTTP/1.1/

My .htaccess Code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/? [L,R=301]
```

Kindly suggest any solution, i am stucked for days...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak regex in last redirect rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/? [L,R=301]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Also keep redirect rules before rewrite ones.